# Sum total and make an array which count by same values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this

```
  data = [
    {
      Category_Name: "Furniture",
      Status_Name: "Available",
      Count: 1
    },
    {
      Category_Name: "License",
      Status_Name: "Available",
      Count: 3
    },
    {
      Category_Name: "Laptop",
      Status_Name: "Good Condition",
      Count: 1
    },
    {
      Category_Name: "Laptop",
      Status_Name: "Good Condition",
      Count: 1
    },
    {
      Category_Name: "Vehicle",
      Status_Name: "Requested",
      Count: 2
    },
    {
      Category_Name: "Furniture",
      Status_Name: "Good Condition",
      Count: 1
    }
  ];
```

I am trying to, first, group by same `Category_Name` and sum count values which I made it right, and second create a new array called `status` inside returned object which will count by status names `(Available, Good Condition and Requested)`. So the final result will be like

```
[
  {
    Category_Name: "Furniture",
    total: 2,
    status: [
      {
        Available: 1,
        Good_Condition: 1,
        Requested: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "License",
    total: 3,
    status: [
      {
        Available: 3,
        Good_Condition: 0,
        Requested: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Laptop",
    total: 2,
    status: [
      {
        Available: 0,
        Good_Condition: 2,
        Requested: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Vehicle",
    total: 2,
    status: [
      {
        Available: 0,
        Good_Condition: 0,
        Requested: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I can only solve up to getting total

```
{
    Category_Name: "Furniture",
    total: 2,
},
..
```

with

```
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          if (holder.hasOwnProperty(d.Category_Name)) {
            holder[d.Category_Name] =
              holder[d.Category_Name] + d.Count;
          } else {
            holder[d.Category_Name] = d.Count;
          }
        });


        for (var prop in holder) {
          obj2.push({ Category_Name: prop, total: holder[prop] });
        }
```

and I am having issue getting status array, If someone could help me , I would very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array reduce and do this, I have made the status an object instead of an array, you can do that if required with a small change.

If the 0 counts for status are not required you can simplify the code by dynamically populating the status counts

```js
const reducer = (a, c) => {
  const item = a.find((x) => x.Category_Name === c.Category_Name);
  const status = c["Status_Name"].replace(' ', '_');
  if (item) {
    item.Total += c.Count;
    item.status[status] += c.Count;
  } else {
    const newItem = {
      Category_Name: c.Category_Name,
      Total: c.Count,
      status: {
        Available: 0,
        Good_Condition: 0,
        Requested: 0
      }
    };
    newItem.status[status] += c.Count;
    a.push(newItem);
  }
  return a;
};

const data = [
  {
    Category_Name: "Furniture",
    Status_Name: "Available",
    Count: 1
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "License",
    Status_Name: "Available",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Laptop",
    Status_Name: "Good Condition",
    Count: 1
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Laptop",
    Status_Name: "Good Condition",
    Count: 1
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Vehicle",
    Status_Name: "Requested",
    Count: 2
  },
  {
    Category_Name: "Furniture",
    Status_Name: "Good Condition",
    Count: 1
  }
];


console.log(data.reduce(reducer, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably shorten this but I've purposely made it verbose so you can see what's going on. I'm first looping through `data` and putting the results in an object named `totals`, in which keys are `Category_Name`. This makes it easy to find a given category name, rather than having to search through an array each time.

Once `totals` has been created, I effectively remove the keys and turn it into an array with `Object.values(totals)`, and store the results in `results`.

```
let totals = {};
  
data.forEach( function(row) {
    if ( totals[row.Category_Name] ) {
        if ( totals[ row.Category_Name ].status[0][ row.Status_Name ] ) {
            totals[ row.Category_Name ].status[0][ row.Status_Name ]++;
        } else {
            totals[ row.Category_Name ].status[0][ row.Status_Name ] = 1;
        }
        totals[ row.Category_Name ].total += row.Count;
    } else {
        totals[row.Category_Name] = {
            Category_Name: row.Category_Name,
            total: row.Count,
            status: [ { [row.Status_Name]: 1 } ] // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/378779
        }
    }
});

let results = Object.values(totals);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help first of all ! However there is one thing I noticed missing, I also want to set default values in an array for other status names if they don't have counts so it will be `Available: 1`,`Good_Condition: 0`, `Requeted: 0`.

Comment: You can do that easily: loop through `results`, and for each element look at its status array, and add any missing status names and their default values.